# Get Google Sheets to Perform Script on Newest Row Only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, twilio

I'm in the process of getting Twilio to send SMS from a Google Sheets. I'm using a basic script provided by a Twilio developer. (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html)

Currently, this code peforms the 'function sendAll()' to every row on the sheet, I want this code to only perform this function on newly added rows.

Or, if this function could be performed on a given row, when a user sets a variable to YES, that would be better.

Thanks in advance.

```
function sendAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    try {
      response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
      status = "sent";
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      status = "error";
    }
    sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 3).setValue(status);
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  sendAll();
}
```

Comment: You must show effort in accomplishing your goal. Show your code and any problem you might have with that. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to setup and onEdit trigger. When you edit a cell to add 'YES' that row will be used to sent an SMS. Insert correct sheet name, save and reload. Then test.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var SHEET_NAME = 'put sheet name here';
  var value = 'YES';

  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  //  check if correct sheet
  if (sheet.getName() != SHEET_NAME) return;

  // check if correct value
  if (e.value != value) return;

  // which row was edited
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  Logger.log(row);
  // get that row values
  var values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  var status;

  try {
    Logger.log(values);
    sendSms(values[0], values[1]);
    status = 'sent';
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    status = 'error';
  }
  sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(status);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I try to run the code it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 26, file "Code")". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to normally run the function like others ? If so, that wont work. Try editing a cell, set value YES.

Comment: My mistake! Sorry, Im new to this. :)

Just to confirm, on this line
`
  try {
    sendSms(values[0], values[1]);
`

values[0] is colunm from which the number is gathered and
values[1] is the body of the message?

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: You used row[0] , row[1] in your code. values[0], values[1] is equivalent

Comment: Your code appears to be working! However, I'm still having trouble getting it to actually read the telephone number and perform the function.... (I once again apologise, this is my first time playing with the Google Apps Scripter). https://gyazo.com/1e0f092c690a33b9ca2915372e062dfc

Comment: Added `Logger.log(values);` line to test. Test again and see View > Logs from menu to see if anything is logged. Besides what error/issue are you having?

Comment: This is the Log I got back "[19-04-16 14:39:59:822 BST] TypeError: Cannot read property "2" from undefined."

Comment: after copying my code did you change anything ? i dont see any 2 in my code

Comment: I started to play with (values[0], values[1]) as in my code, these were configurable as [0]=the rows of which the telephone number was pulled from and [1]=the body of the message.

I changed them back to the exact code you sent me, and got this in the logs. "[19-04-16 14:46:40:601 BST] undefined
[19-04-16 14:46:40:602 BST] TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined."

Comment: added `Logger.log(row);`, try again. edit a cell that is in right of cells with number and body. check logs

Comment: I changed the sendSms row to now say "sendSms(row[1],'Test');"

The log now says:
"[19-04-16 15:06:02:370 BST] 3.0
[19-04-16 15:06:02:586 BST] undefined"

Comment: row is a number. it logged 3 means you edited in a cell that is in row 3. sendSms(row[1],'Test'); will not work. dont mix your code and mine

Comment: Sorry. I changed it back to your code and changed sendSms to "sendSms(values[3],values[1]);" and got this in the log: "[19-04-16 15:48:43:103 BST] 3.0
[19-04-16 15:48:43:263 BST] undefined
[19-04-16 15:48:43:264 BST] TypeError: Cannot read property "3" from undefined."

Comment: values is undefined so, nothing inside [] after values will work. strange, i see no error, no reason for values to be undefined. works fine here